# Steps to debug failed systemctl service response

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a Hybris server on an AWS EC2 instance. When I try to start the server using `systemctl start hybris.service` I get the following error:

```
Job for hybris.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

When I try to navigate to the platform and run `./hybrisserver.sh start`, I am able to start the server successfully. On running `journalctl -xe` further, I get the following results:

```
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 systemd[23757]: hybris.service: Failed at step CHROOT spawning /opt/sap/hybris/bin/platform/hyb
-- Subject: Process /opt/sap/hybris/bin/platform/hybrisserver.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- The process /opt/sap/hybris/bin/platform/hybrisserver.sh could not be executed and failed.
-- 
-- The error number returned by this process is 2.
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 systemd[1]: hybris.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=210
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 systemd[1]: Failed to start Hybris Server.
-- Subject: Unit hybris.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
-- 
-- Unit hybris.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 systemd[1]: hybris.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 systemd[1]: hybris.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 20:13:35 ip-10-41-19-107 polkitd(authority=local)[10171]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:23746:56770
```

How can I figure out what `code=exited status=210` corresponds to, and how can I fix this?